# file existence checker on a remote serveralways returning 255

Tags: python, subprocess, paramiko, remote-server

When I try running this code (variable names changed). It is always returning 255 for some reason. I'm trying to check if a file with a certain name exists on a remote server or not. Is there any mistake here if not then is there any other method I can use to achieve my purpose of checking if a file with a certain name exists in a remote server or not. (Python paramiko library is what I used to connect to the server.)

```
import subprocess
import pipes

ssh_host = 'host_adress'
file = 'file_loc'

resp = subprocess.call(
    ['ssh', ssh_host, 'test -e ' + pipes.quote(file)])

if resp == 0:
    print ('%s exists' % file)
else:
    print ('%s does not exist' % file)
```

Comment: sorry for the late response I finally figured it out. I gave up on this solution by just using a filenotfound error and a try/except function.

Answer (score -1):

Using the requests package seems to work:

```
import requests

source_url = "https://blah blah"

try:
    downloaded_data = requests.get(source_url)
    print("Success")
except:
    print("Data cannot be downloaded")
```

Comment: I’m trying to see if a file exists on a server not download the file.  Does the requests packet do that if I’ve already connected to the server using paramiko?